# Incompatible Types "LongBool" and "Integer"

Tags: delphi

I needed to compile the source code of Inno Media Player 0.03 which was modified by me to add a Cursor Hiding feature to it using Delphi.

I added the code to the source successfully and tried to recompile but the compiler says:

> [dcc32 Error] MainUnit.pas(154): E2010 Incompatible types: 'LongBool' and 'Integer'.

What is the problem in this code?

The code I added to INNO MEDIA PLAYER:

```
const
  OATRUE = -1;

procedure TDirectShowPlayer.InitializeVideoWindow(WindowHandle: HWND; var Width,
  Height: Integer);
begin
  ErrorCheck(FGraphBuilder.QueryInterface(IVideoWindow, FVideoWindow));
  ErrorCheck(FVideoWindow.HideCursor(OATRUE));     **<<<ERROR IS HERE<<<**
  ...
end;
```

I called the `IVideoWindow::HideCursor` method on the `FVideoWindow` in the `TDirectShowPlayer.InitializeVideoWindow`.

The `OATRUE` Constant is a `System.Shortint` and `IVideoWindow.HideCursor` is a `LongBool` method.

Are those incompatible types or is my version of Delphi incompatible with this code that I added ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [DirectShow documentation on `IVideoWindow::HideCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377306(v=vs.85).aspx) method signature is:

```
HRESULT HideCursor(
  [in] long HideCursor
);
```

while corresponding signature in Progdigy's Pascal translation is:

```
function HideCursor(HideCursor: LongBool): HResult; stdcall;
```

So, while your code is absolutely complies to MS specification, you have to deal with incorrect type declaration somehow. You need to typecast your constant to declared type:

```
ErrorCheck(FVideoWindow.HideCursor(LongBool(OATRUE)));
```

Note: just passing `True` to `HideCursor` might also work provided DirectShow isn't sensitive to exact values. Use with caution.

Comment: Now the error is gone and I compiled sucessfully.Thank you very much.            But I am surprised why my mouse cursor still not hiding from video ?

Comment: You should select one of the answers as correct, even though they both say much the same thing.  Your visible cursor is another issue not really covered in the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

On MSDN, `IVideoWindow.HideCursor()` is declared as taking a `long` as input, not a `BOOL`, so it should not be declared as `LongBool` in Delphi, it should be `Longint` instead. So either fix the declaration, or use a typecast:

```
ErrorCheck(FVideoWindow.HideCursor(BOOL(OATRUE)));
```